# IntelliJ Idea 14 doesn't show grails domain class methods in auto suggest

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Title conveys my problem.

I have Grails domain and Controller classes.

From my Controller, I try DomainClass.(ctrl+space) but i don't get any suggestions

Please help

Comment: grails 2, grails 3? ran some `grails package`? other projects/controllers/domainclasses work?

Comment: Grails 2.4.4 Didn't run any grails package. Domain and controllers are of the same project in respective Domain and Controller Folders with identical package structures. Run time code works fine, but idea doesn't give suggestions

Comment: right click your project root, `grails`, `synchronize grails settings`,  then run the grails target `package`. restart helps sometimes too.  the usual IDE raindance...